# Tensor algebra and symmetric algebra

Tags: tensors

Reference Book : Dummit - abstract algebra 3rd edition (page 455).
[image]

But, I think  $ $ $=$ $ $ notation is not correct. It may be corrected to $\cong$ (an isomorphic notation). Because $S^2 (V)$, $\wedge^2(V)$ are not submodule of 
$V \otimes_F V$ . If we use the identification, it is true. 
Am I right? Actually, I have a lot of stress from this book because of too many erratas.

Comment: It is equality, not isomorphism. Note that Dummit and Foote define $S^2(V)$ and $\bigwedge^2(V)$ as subspaces of $V\otimes V$, not quotients.

Comment: @Michael Albanese / The context defines $S^2 (V)$ as $\frac{V \otimes V}{J^2}$ where $J^2$ is genereted by all elements of the form $m \otimes m$ for each $m \in V$. Is it a subspace of the tensor product $ V \otimes V$?

Comment: You're right, I misread. In that case, it should be an isomorphism.

Comment: @Michae lAlbanese / Thank you for your kind answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you define $S^2$ and $\Lambda^2$: the book may define $S^2(V) = \langle v\otimes w+w\otimes v:v,w\in V\rangle$ and $\Lambda^2= \langle v\otimes w-w\otimes v: v,w \in V\rangle$ in which case = is true. If you define them differently then perhaps = is not literally true, but it's very common to mildly abuse notation like this.  Indeed it's almost essential at times: with usual definitions, $(A\oplus B)\oplus C$ and $A\oplus (B\oplus C)$ are not literally the same vector space, but keeping track of the isomorphisms involved is surely more trouble that it is worth.

Comment: @ mt_ / Thank you for your kind answer.